# How to use user input value as part of regular expression for other field validation in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, regex

I have 2 fields with their respective `ng-model` fields. I want to use 1st field value in 2nd field's `ng-pattern` expression. E.g.

`EmployeeID` and `EmployeeFile` fields. 
`EmployeeID` is mapped to `$scope.empId`.
`EmployeeFile` is mapped to `$scope.file`. For validating file input, the pattern should be like `^.{{$scope.empId}}-\d{3}\.(xls|xlsx)$`.

Is is possible to have one model affect another regex validator for another field in AngularJS?

I've got something like

```
<input type="text" ng-model="emp.empId"> 
<input type="text" ng-model="emp.empFile" ng-pattern=".....">
```

What should I fill in the `ng-pattern` if I want the value to be `{{empId}}.xls`?

Comment: Is the question not clear? Can anyone help

Comment: you can try to provide some code to show the order of your input fields for better understanding (which input has `ng-pattern`, which needs validation, etc.)

Comment: <input type="text" name="txtEmpId" id="txtEmpId" ng-model="emp.empId" placeholder="Employee Id">                                                                               <input type="text" name="txtEmpFile" id="txtEmpFile" ng-model="emp.empFile" ng-pattern="....." placeholder="Employee File">...What should I fill in ng-pattern if I want the value to be {{empId}}.xls always .

Comment: _you can edit your question and add any relevant code_

Comment: I got the fix. We can pass the empId field value to new RegExp() and use pattern.test(value to test) for validation. Thanks.Closing this issue.

Comment: can you share your  method

Answer (score 0):

first you should replace the data with empId and check with reg-exp and again concat the matched reg-exp content and dynamic empId  and check

```
  inputValue=scope.file.replace($scope.empid,'');
   regexp = ^.-\d{3}.(xls|xlsx)$"; //without empid 
     var transformedInput = inputValue.match(REGEXP);
        if (transformedInput==inputValue) {
          validfile = $scope.empid+inputValue;

  }
```